# Photoshop scripts - Automatically color the error areas

Tags: colors, scripting, photoshop, fill

I have a lot of .psd files in the E:\4. New

These files have many layers, include: 1 color layer and 1 black stroke layer (and shadow layer, light layer, ...)
There is a problem with these files: there are some locations that have not been colored (refers to the color layer and  black stroke layer ) (visit note.png for better understanding)

These file in this link:

https://mega.nz/folder/aolgXL5B#tIx8DONXDJ8ttzVHKfvakg

I am a beginner so I really need your help to solve this problem.

The process may be like that:

1. I select black brushstroke layer and color layer
2. I run the code to automatically color the error areas

Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried, what didn't work? For the moment it looks like you just want someone to write a script for you for free

Comment: You will have to elaborate on "automatically color the error areas". Automatically how?? That may sound trivial, I suspect it's much more complex. If you can write the pseudo code for it, others can help you. But as @SergeyKritskiy says, this is not a script writing service.